# Markov chain - Expectation $+1$?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, conditional-expectation

> Let the transition matrix of a markov chain with states $\{0,1,2\}$ :
>
> \begin{equation} A=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} &
>  \frac{1}{3} \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\\ 0 & 0 & 1
>  \end{bmatrix}. \end{equation}
>
> Explain why the state $2$ is absorbing and calculate the average time
>   of absorption if we start at the state $0$.

**(1)** The state 2 is absorbing since $P_{22}=1$.

**(2)** Let $\tau_i=E($time to reach the state $2 = N$ $|$ starting at $i$$)$

**(*)**$$\tau_i=E(N|X_t=i)=\sum_k E(N|X_t=i, X_{t+1}=k)P(X_{t+1}=k | X_t=i) = \sum_k E(N|X_{t+1}=k)P_{ik}$$

Thus I could develop the system of equations :

$$\tau_0= \frac{1}{3} \tau_0 + \frac{1}{3} \tau_1+ \frac{1}{3} \tau_2$$
$$\tau_1= \frac{1}{2} \tau_1 + \frac{1}{2} \tau_2$$
$$\tau_2=1$$

So I found $\tau_0= \frac{5}{6}$

I think I have to add $1$ at some place at **(*)**. Does anyone could explain to me rigourously why $E(N|X_t=i, X_{t+1}=k)=E(N+1|X_{t+1}=k)$?

Comment: It's not rigorous, but if $X_t$ is not the absorbing state, then using the Markov property you can reformulate as the expectation of $N+1$ steps, knowing that $X_t$ wasn't the absorbing one. You're like shifting the count.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking $1$ step and then you see where you are.

Let $\tau(i)$ be the expected time to reach the absorbing state $2$ from state $i$, where $i =\{0,1,2\}$.

$\tau(0) = 1 +\frac{1}{3}\tau(0)+\frac{1}{3}\tau(1)+\frac{1}{3}\tau(2)$

$\tau(1) = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\tau(1)+\frac{1}{2}\tau(2)$

$\tau(2) =0$

Solve the system to find $\tau(0)$.

Comment: I know all that, but you don't answer my question

Comment: @Dr.Dray How can you know all this when your equations and solution are wrong?

Comment: The solution sheet of the teacher. I need someone explain to me why my question is true.

Comment: Any solution sheet explaining that $\tau_0=\frac56$ where $\tau_0$ denotes the expectation of a hitting time always at least $1$ should be met with a healthy dose of skepticism.